# Primer type for exterior PVC lumber

Tags: paint, pvc, primer

I have exterior PVC lumber (e.g. Azec) as brick molding and would like to paint it. Should I use regular water based primer or oil based like with metal surfaces?

Comment: Does the manufacturer specify?

Comment: i googled but didn't find anything

Answer (score 2):

You'll likely need a *bonding primer* as they are designed to provide better adhesion to *hard to stick* surfaces such as plastics and metal.

Call your local paint stores and see what they have available or go to the big box hardware store and get your self a spray can of Rustoleum Bonding Primer.

Comment: "better adhesion to hard to stick surfaces such as plastics and metal" -- can i just use oil based primer, which does that also?

Comment: Not all primers are the same, oil primers are designed to penetrate porous surfaces like wood/wood products. In this case, I would look for a bonding primer that specifically states it will bond to plastics.

Answer (score 1):

If it is AZEK (tm), then https://azekexteriors.com/resources/painting and https://azekexteriors.com/docs/paint-pro/ss-azek-paintpro-paint-guide.pdf (tldr: no primer needed).

As an aside, I found this contrary to my expectations, which is why talking to the manufacturer of your specific product is often useful.

Comment: The link provided has some great info on LRV and such, however, I would say that a primer is still advisable as most paints require a properly prepared surface which means clean from dirt/debris and a suitable primer applied before painting.  +1 for LRV info, excellent thing to consider.

Comment: @matt — I’d ordinarily agree with you, but the second link, the pdf, is pretty specific.

Comment: Interesting, it does clearly state priming is not required. I'm surprised to say the least. Good catch.